# How to construct urls for job names for downloading latest artifacts in GitLab CI?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I am using the [downloading latest artifact feature](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/job_artifacts.html#downloading-the-latest-artifacts).

For me it is not clear, how the job name I need to pass is created: my job name contains e.g. spaces, equal signs and brackets:

```
build win: [USE_PYTHON=ON]
```

I know that spaces are replaced by `+`-signs but what about the others characters?

Changing the job name is not an option because I use the [matrix](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#parallel-matrix-jobs)-feature and it creates names like these.

Thanks a lot for your help!

Example ci yaml:

```yaml
build win:
  ...
  parallel:
    matrix:
      - USE_PYTHON: ["USE_PYTHON=ON", "USE_PYTHON=OFF"]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ASCII encoding like for space %20.

Find them here
https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.ASP

Comment: Thanks it works! Just enter the job name into the "try it yourself" form on https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.ASP and you get the correct form.

Comment: Great. Glad it helped. :)